# Knockout click binding doesnt fire on click

Tags: javascript, click, knockout-3.0

Just setup a basic knokcout view model and respective html view, but the click function doesnt fire.

```
<script>
    new myModel.XYZ();
</script>

<div id="bar-1">
    <button
            title="Get Document"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            data-bind="click: getDocument">
        <span class="fas fa-file-alt"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

and my view model is setup as;

```
myModel.XYZ = function (par) {
    var self = this;

    self.getDocument = function(submission) {
       alert('');
       }
    ko.applyBindings(self, $("#bar-1")[0]);
};
```

There's no console error or anything else that could help me find out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly agree with @erpfast, But if you still want to implement your way, you forgot to declare myModel and added method on Object.

```js
var myModel ={};
myModel.XYZ = function (par) {
    var self = this;

    self.getDocument = function(submission) {
       alert('');
       }
    ko.applyBindings(self, $("#bar-1")[0]);
};

new myModel.XYZ();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar-1">
    <button
            title="Get Document"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            data-bind="click: getDocument">
            Button
        <span class="fas fa-file-alt"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define your model

```
var myModel = function(par) {
   var self = this;
   self.getDocument = function(submission) {
      alert('');
   }
}
```

Then set your binding

```
ko.applyBindings(new myModel(document.getElementById("#bar-1")));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8o1p6tub/36/)

Comment: I don't see anything different to the solution I posted.

Comment: Please take another look at how you're binding. You're doing it inside of the model. Check the JSFiddle.